# Public games for solving open problems

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Many people in the world like playing games. Also, maybe we can design special interesting games for some open problems in mathematics (or physics).

In quantum mechanics, there are some games (for example, Quantum Moves; which it is about quantum control and hybrid intelligence [About the Game](https://www.scienceathome.org/games/quantum-moves-2/science-behind-quantum-moves-2/)) that if you play a game and can finish it, you solved an open problem. For example (simplified explanation), there is a bucket of water and a lot of obstacles (hills and pits). If you can move the bucket to the end of the road and there are specific amount of water on the bucket, you solved an open problem in quantum mechanics (you solved an equation in quantum mechanics). The game is so funny and everyone can play it without any knowledge about the quantum mechanics [Quantum Moves](https://www.nature.com/news/human-mind-excels-at-quantum-physics-computer-game-1.19725).

My question is:

**Are there similar games for solving open problems in mathematics (or in physics)?**

Comment: Jigsaw puzzles and the Riemann Hypothesis, https://www.dr-mikes-math-games-for-kids.com/blog/2014/05/jigsaw-puzzles-and-the-riemann-hypothesis/

Comment: Not directly related, but some time ago I gamified a problem I had solved by computer to see if it'd be fun to solve by hand. It was NOT http://villesalo.com/kuluma/e57game.html

Comment: Do you mean games that have actually been advertised to the public as something fun to play, or are you talking about games in an abstract sense? Because there are some open problems that are *about* games.

Comment: @PyRulez  I mean the games that are fun to play.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe the start of citizen-science games for scientific research
was [FoldIt](https://fold.it/portal/info/about),
asking users to find a low potential energy configurations of protein molecules.
Some publishable results were achieved.<sup>1</sup>

---

[image]

---

Wikipedia has a list of citizen-science projects [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_citizen_science_projects).
Only one is marked as "Mathematics":
[SZTAKI Desktop Grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SZTAKI_Desktop_Grid),
closed two years ago.
There are several labeled Physics, including
[Quantum Moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Moves)
as mentioned by the OP.
Astronomy projects are prevalent, e.g., [Planet Hunters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Hunters).

---

<sup>1</sup>Cooper S, Khatib F, Treuille A, Barbero J, Lee J, Beenen M, et al. (August 2010). "Predicting protein structures with a multiplayer online game." *Nature*. 466 (7307): 756–60.